# Reading data from sql server in databricks(pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a task where I need to read data from Sql server table in Databricks notebook. I am using Pyspark for the transformation.

My question is how many connection pyspark will open with sql server to read the data ? does it depend on the number of maps created by the job ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spark will read data via JDBC only into one partition, so it should open one or two connections.  But this is very inefficient, so it's [recommended](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#jdbc-reads) to specify `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, and `numPartitions` parameters, so reading of data will happen in parallel - but this is heavily dependent on if you have a column (numeric, timestamp or something like) that could be used to split data into given number of partitions. With these options, Spark will open something like `min(numPartitions, num CPU cores)` connections.

Comment: Thanks Alex, is it best practice to connect to sql server and read the data or get the data into data lake and than apply transformation ? I feel connecting to sql server with multiple connection is not right approach as it will burden the sql server database ?

Comment: it really depends on the freshness of data, and other requirements. if you can get dump out of SQL server & do analysis - it would be more performant & less load on SQL server. But really there are many aspects that it's hard to generalize